# If $P(x)$ is characteristic polynomial of $A$ then is $P(A) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm a student and I've just read the [Characteristic polynomial on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial).
I have a feeling that:

> If $P(x)$ is characteristic polynomial of $A$ then is $P(A) = 0$

thanks to the [Matrix calculator](https://matrixcalc.org/en/#%7B%7B-1,1%7D,%7B-1,1%7D%7D%5E2) I've tested it for the matrix that is the wikis example and another matrix, and this was true for both of them. the matrices were $ \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\-1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $ and $ \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

I've thought about it. if the eigenvectors of the matrix span the space. so we can write every vector in the space as a linear combination of its eigenvectors. So for every $v$ in space $P(A)v = P(A)(\alpha_1e_1 +  \alpha_2e_2 + ...)$ and it is easy to see that for every $e_i$ there is $P(A)e_i = 0$

BUT the problem is for the matrices like $ \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ that dosent have $n$ distinct eigenvectors that span the space. I have no idea for this kind.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is in the article you read: *"The [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) states that replacing t by A in the characteristic polynomial (interpreting the resulting powers as matrix powers, and the constant term c as c times the identity matrix) yields the zero matrix."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. Actually, that's what the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) says.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.